# Calculating the velocity of a proton through Relativity Theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, kinematics, velocity, protons

I was asked to calculate the velocity of a proton through Relativity Theory, with the following information given:

-the Total Energy of the proton is 1,500 MeV

-the resting mass ($m_0$) of the proton is 938 MeV/c^2

The answer key gives the answer based on the formula $β = (1-\frac{1}{γ^2})^\frac{1}{2}$. They first calculate γ through $γ = \frac{Ε}{m_0c^2}$ with γ coming out as 1500/938=1.6. β then works out as 0.78. They then insert this into β=v/c, to give v=0.78c.

I used the formula $\frac{m_0c^2}{E}=cosβ$, after which I computed β based on cosβ. I then inserted the result into β=v/c. I wasn't sure whether I should use radians or degrees in order to compute β here, but I tried both. Yet the results are different from the above. Obviously there is a mistake in my reasoning, but I have no idea where. What did I do wrong?

Equations from my Textbook:

$$m_0c^2/E=\cos\beta$$$$\beta=v/c$$

Comment: Where did you get the formula you used? I don't think it's correct.

Comment: @Pregunto: What is this $\cos \beta$ that you are talking about? The formula for total energy is $\gamma m c^2$, and rest energy is $mc^2$, and that's it.

Comment: @puppetsock
The cosβ formula comes straight from my textbook…
I have edited the original post by adding two screenshots of the relevant formulas (just to make sure I am not in the wrong here). Could you have a look at it?

Comment: @user7777777
The cosβ formula comes straight from my textbook…
I have edited the original post by adding two screenshots of the relevant formulas (just to make sure I am not in the wrong here). Could you have a look at it?

Comment: Note that for $\beta \ll 1$, we have $$\frac{m_0c^2}{E} = \sqrt{1-\beta^2}\approx 1 - \frac{\beta^2}{2} \approx \cos\beta$$

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please use this tag on this type of question.

Comment: What textbook are you using? Defining this $\cos(\beta)$ seems pretty nonstandard, if not wrong.

Comment: I think the first equation from your textbook is wrong.  Should be $m_0c^2/E=\cos\arcsin\beta$ if you want to write it with trig functions.  See [this diagram](https://thespectrumofriemannium.files.wordpress.com/2012/06/trigomnemo2good2.png) for example.

Answer (score 3):

> What did I do wrong?

You applied an approximation outside of the region where it is valid.  The total energy of a (free) particle with invariant mass $m_0$ (or better, just $m$) and speed $v$ is given by

$$E = \gamma m c^2 = \frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1 - \beta^2}},\quad \beta\equiv\frac{v}{c}$$

For $v\ll c,\,\beta \ll 1$ and we can use the approximation

$$\sqrt{1 - \beta^2}\approx 1 - \frac{\beta^2}{2},\quad \beta\ll 1$$

Now, look at the Taylor expansion of $\cos\beta$

$$\cos\beta = 1 - \frac{\beta^2}{2} + \frac{\beta^4}{24} - \cdots$$

so, in the regime $\beta \ll 1$, we have

$$\sqrt{1 - \beta^2} \approx \cos\beta$$

Now, if you use this approximation for the parameters given, you get

$$\beta = \cos^{-1}\frac{938}{1500} = 0.8952... $$

Do you see the problem?  Starting with the assumption that $\beta$ is *much* less than one, you calculate a value of $\beta$ that is *quite close* to one!  In other words, you can't use that approximation here.  Instead, you must use the exact expression to find

$$\beta = \sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{938}{1500}\right)^2} = 0.7803...$$

Answer (score 1):

The "textbook" equations posted in the OP are incorrect 
but can be corrected as follows:

$$m_0 c^2/E={\color{red}\cosh(\color{red}\tanh^{\color{red} -\color{red} 1}\beta})$$ and $$\beta=v/c$$

Using the **Rapidity** $\theta=\tanh^{-1}\beta = \tanh^{-1}(v/c)$,
this can be rewritten as
$$m_0 c^2/E={\color{red}\cosh\color{red}\theta}=\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}$$
$$\tanh\theta=\beta=(v/c)$$
Note that $1=\cosh^2\theta-\sinh^2\theta=\cosh^2\theta(1-\tanh^2\theta)=\gamma^2(1-\beta^2)$.

Using WolframAlpha, 

 **tanh(arccosh(1500/938))=0.7803577527148828.**

*If you draw an energy-momentum diagram, you are basically finding the slope of a triangle given the hypotenuse and the adjacent side (in Minkowski spacetime geometry).*